# Android: add actions from Menu to own title bar RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, menu, android-relativelayout

In Android project most Activities have ActionBar disabled with style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and use own title bar that is based on RelativeLayout via `include`

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/activity_title_bar"
    layout="@layout/view_title_bar" />
```

There is no intetion of using ActionBar but I would like to find how to implement adding Menu item on title bar like ActionBar does.

Currently those actions are defined in res/menun/common_actions.xml 
and visible via options menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.common_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_home:
            MainActivity.start(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            SearchActivity.start(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

However options menu button is not available on newer devices.

**How to implement adding actions to title bar RelativeLayout?**
There is no need for all Actionbar logic, just take 2 actions with icons from defined menu and put them on title bar.

Related docs:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 1):

You should really just use the `Toolbar`. It's rather quite simple and you can achieve exactly what you want...

..but to achieve what you want, you would use a [`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) and anchor it to an `ImageView` or `ImageButton` that looks like the overflow menu.